# $(p-2)!-1 \neq p^k$ for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $p$ is a prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$(p-2)!-1 \neq p^k$ for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $p>5$, $p$ is a prime.

How to solve this?

Comment: If this is from an analytic number theory course, please tag it as such. calculus is not the tag. Also I changed number-theory to elementary-number-theory. Feel free to change it back, if it is an advanced course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p > 5$ is prime, then  at least one of the following is true:

1. $p-1$ is divisible by $q = 4 \le p-2$.
2. $p-1$ is divisible by an odd prime $q \le p-2$.

In either case, we have $(p-2)! \equiv 0 \mod q$ as well as $p \equiv 1 \mod q$.
This implies that
$$0 \equiv (p-2)! = p^k + 1 \equiv 1^k + 1 \equiv 1 + 1 \equiv 2 \mod q,$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Nice one here ! What's with this name though ? ...

Answer (score 0):

I removed my previous answer because there was a mistake in it and it made it become useless, but still I guess you could try it by assuming the "opposite" of your proposition:

$$\exists k\in\Bbb{N},\space (p-2)!-1=p^k$$

If you arrive at something impossible, this will mean the beginning assumption was wrong.

Thus you get your result (which is the opposite of your (wrong) assumption):

$$\forall k\in\Bbb{N},\space (p-2)!-1\neq p^k$$ (for prime $p>5$)

This comes from the fact that if proposition $\urcorner A$ leads to something wrong using valid reasoning, then $\urcorner A$ is itself wrong and thus $A$ is true.

Comment: I believe you have erred in multiplying by $p(p-1)$.  It seems you forgot to distribute it through to the $-1$ as well.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern Oh yes, cr** ...

Comment: I think that's the right way to go about it, though.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern Still works ovrall though, I'm going to change this (and the summation is not necessary either ... poor proof :))

Comment: @FrankMcGovern No it doesn't work anymore: it's now an odd number equal to another odd number ... too bad, liked this proof :(